# Need to access multiple methods in order to compare objects

Tags: java, list, arraylist, lambda, comparator

After reading the Oracle docs I did not found what I am looking for. I have an object that it can be compared in different ways, but one of its attributes is a List. How can I compare based on the size of the that List attribute?

```
Comparator comparator = Comparator.comparing(Product::getCommentList::size);
List<Product> soldL = new LinkedList();
soldL.addAll(sold);
Collections.sort(soldL,comparator);
```

I tried the code above without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use lambda and improve your existing code as :

```
Comparator<Product> comparator = Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getCommentList().size()); // type 'Product' bound
List<Product> soldL = new LinkedList<>(); // type inferred '<>'
soldL.addAll(sold);
soldL.sort(comparator); // use 'List.sort'
```

***Edit***: You can make use of the `comparingInt` instead of comparaing to avoid boxing as:

```
Comparator<Product> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.getCommentList().size());
```

Comment: Can use `Comparator.comparingInt` to avoid the additional boxing

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the comparison by implementing a method on Product that returns the size of the list (ex: `public int getCommentListSize() { return commentList.size(); }`).

So you can create a comparator this way:

```
Comparator comparator = Comparator.comparing(Product::getCommentListSize);
```

After that, you pass comparator to the sort method.